# Does each element of $D4$ have an inverse in $D4$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, function-and-relation-composition

We are just starting the concept of permutations of objects in my class and I'm having trouble to grasp this particular question.

I'm assuming it does have an inverse because of all the different permutations, but that is just a guess.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What definition of "permutation" are you using?

Comment: one permutation say of $S3$ is (1)(2)(3). That's how I would describe it.

Comment: I didn't ask for an example of a permutation. What is the *definition* of permutation that you're using? That is, what does "permutation" mean?

Comment: $D_4$ can be expressed different ways, so we don't exactly know your definition. Since it's a group, it has inverses, but it seems you don't know it as a group, but rather a collection of permutations. The inverse of a permutation $f:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is just the inverse function $f^{-1}$. If you know $D_4$ as a collection of permutations, then for each permutation in your realization of $D_4$, show that the inverse permutation is also in $D_4$.

Comment: Each element of $D_n$ is generated by rotations and reflections of a polygon of $n$ sides. It is easy to find an inverse of these generators.